# Displaying the error in production mode with log number in laravel

Tags: laravel, logging, error-handling, eloquent, runtime-error

I have an application built in **laravel 5.8** which is in **production mode**. As the site is live I don't want to display any errors to our users. But If some error occurs then I want the log number or any reference that indicates what error was thrown at that particular time.

So I wanted to know if there is any way to display **"Oops something went wrong ref#123456"** to our users. So that they can send us a screenshot or reference number and we can track what actually happend by checking our **log file**.

Thanks in advance. Happy coding.

Comment: Aside, I’d like to see more web applications doing something like that. As a developer, it would save a lot of time trying to isolate a request in the logs. And, as a user, it would give me more confidence (for right or for wrong) that reporting it will actually solve something.

Comment: tbh it sounds like you should be testing your code better. Fix everything that causes such errors. Use an error tracker like Sentry.io or simply periodically check the logs yourself.

Answer (score 6):

I thing that you can do it saving the logs in database and render its id.

You can do it in `App\Exceptions\Handler`:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors

For example:

```
    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Throwable  $exception
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     *
     * @throws \Throwable
     */
    public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
    {
        // Create log in db
        $log = Log::create([
            'message' => $exception->getMessage(), 
            'code' => $exception->getCode(),
            'line' => $exception->getLine(),
        ]);

        // Print log id in logs
        logger("LogId {$log->id}");

        //Return view error with log id
        return return response()->view('errors', ['logId' => $log->id]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want something more professional than logging the exception, and laravel have a great package for it named telescope you got all your exceptions and queries or events redis and ... so many. you can authorize the users that only admins can access telescope information. and because its a lot of info probably you want prune the records with a seceule:

```
$schedule->command('telescope:prune --hours=48')->daily();
```

all of this you can find it in docs: https://laravel.com/docs/telescope

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as using `uniqueid()` function to create an id for an exception, and returning a view in the render part of your app.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    $errorCode = uniqid('error_');

    Log::error("$errorCode", [
        //... The log information here
    ]);

    return view('welcome', compact('errorCode'));
}
```

As an example above I am using the default `welcome.blade.php` page, and then showing the content below:

> **Error occurred #error_5ec385d7c4d25**

It means you can actually search your logs for this error code to know what went wrong.